# No communication between Ledger Nano S and Stellar account viewer

Tags: stellar-core

If I try to connect the ledger Nano S to the Stellar account viewer, the relating field in the account viewer does not turn blue, but stays grey.
So the ledger has not been detected by the account viewer, I think.
I tried it several times, also in private mode, as suggested.
But nothing works. What would be a solution?

Comment: I have the same problem like you but in my situation I can login to Stellar account but I cant send coins to my wallet address in Binance , may you can do refresh when you connect the ledger and open Stellar app .

Comment: what do you mean with refresh, while connecting the ledger and the stellar app.